# Atualização manual da Versão PHP

Tags: php, apache

Desenvolvi *scripts* em PHP compatíveis com a versão mínima 5.3.7, e para minha infelicidade, a versão que está instalada no servidor Apache é 5.2.17.

Como posso manualmente subir a nova versão PHP via ftp para atualizar?

Pesquisei algumas coisas do tipo:

- Pode ser feito através de um arquivo .htaccess, que deve ficar na pasta onde possuo meus *scripts*, informando ao servidor que naquela pasta será executa a versão especificada do PHP.

  ```
  AddHandler php53-script .php .php5 .php56 .pht .phtm .phtml
  suPHP_ConfigPath /home/user/public_html/quero_que_seja_executada_a_nova_versão_nesta_pasta
  ```

o problema disso é o arquivo php.ini, que não sei se posso indicar para ler o meu, e não o do servidor.

- Pode ser feito criando um Apache Handler direto co cPanel
- Há quem diga que não têm como, pois é exclusivamente feito no servidor na pasta bin do Apache

Alguém sabe como, ou pelo menos me ilumine, com alguma forma onde  posso fazer isso?

Comment: Renan você terá que entrar em contato com o seu provedor de hospedagem. Não é possível subir o executável do PHP via FTP e rodar sua aplicação por ele até onde sei.

Comment: Vc ta usando que tipo de OS no servidor? Windows, Debian? Se o hospedag e do tipo "shared hosting" vc não pode. Vc pode somente se vc tem um servido "dedicado". Tem tambem uma outro pergunta: tem quasi nunca diferencia entre PHP 5.2 e 5.3. Que tipo de coisa vc faz, que não funciona sobre PHP5.2??

Comment: Nota: o PHP 5.3 já não é mais suportado e as versões mais novas tem um desempenho superior a 5.3. Recomendo a atualização para uma versão mais recente.

Comment: @Peter entre o 5.2 e 5.3 temos o suporte a namespaces. Só isso já acho o suficuente.

Comment: Se e isso, então: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6473126/namespaces-in-php-5-2  Mas não sei se vai resolver.

Comment: Minha sugestão está mais em mudar a hospedagem se possível, ou entrar em contato com o suporte para eles atualizarem.

Comment: é que eu realmente preciso dessa versão mais atual pois estou usando funções de hashing de senha, sem falar que me exibiu um erro: 

Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by (output started at /home/fenix/public_html/login/admin/index.php:4) in /home/fenix/public_html/login/admin/classes/Login.php on line 40

Comment: Se o servidor não é seu, você não pode, se for uma hospedagem eu acho que o seu servidor deve ter algo semelhante ao Cpanel, lá você pode escolher a versão do PHP (geralmente tem mais de uma instalada), na hospedagem de um cliente eu tenho 5.2, 5.3, 5.4 e 5.5; eu alterno quando quiser.

Answer (score 1):

Se é possível ou não utilizar seu php.ini personalizado depende das configurações do apache.

Basta você colocar na raiz do seu site, se funcionar é por que é possível (:

O arquivo .htaccess já é limitado pela pasta onde ele esta. Então você não precisa da segunda linha do código que colou. No entanto mudar a versão só será possível caso seu serviço de hospedagem tenha a versão que você esta tentando usar disponível.

Quanto ao erro que você reportou nos comentários, é possível que o erro exista no seu ambiente de desenvolvimento, ele só aparece no ambiente de produção devido à diretiva **error_reporting**.

Você pode suprimir os erros usando uma função php mesmo:

```
error_reporting(E_ERROR);
```

No entanto é recomendado que você configure seu ambiente de desenvolvimento para mostrar todos os erros, e verifique e corrija os erros ao invés de simplesmente escodê-los.

Por exemplo o erro que você postou nos comentários é geralmente causado por espaço em branco e ou qualquer outro tipo de texto/html, funções como echo e print utilizadas antes da função header.

Se você tem arquivos .php que não contêm html/texto é indicado que você não feche a tag php.
Ex.:

```
<?php
   function util(){ 
     //fazalgo 
   };
//fim do arquivo sem fechar php porque não tem html depois
```

Comment: obrigado a todos. realmente tive que entrar em contato com a hospedagem para eles fazerem tudo por lá.